# Paypal Express checkout Smart Button Blocked a frame with Origin

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I integrated paypal Express Checkout through Smart button SDK in a page. This integrated page included in another page by iframe.

The site is : www.kickpages.com/getpro where iframe of registration page loaded. Its work fine but sometime I get below error:

Blocked a frame with Origin

Can anyone help me?